# City centre of Zurich

Tags: online-resources, maps, zurich

It will be very helpful if someone spots the city centre of Zurich in Google Maps.

Comment: A little more context and why you want that would help in answering this

Comment: why that? The question is crystsal clear. Length is not an indicator of quality

Comment: @user3470 I've got to disagree. It is not a question, and it is not crystal clear.

Comment: Feel free to disagree, but it's clear. The guy wants to know how to find the city. The thing is not formulated as a question but that is just a formality

Comment: @sibani, if there is still some info missing, please comment below. Otherwise, if you think the answers are sufficient, please "accept" on of them

Comment: Zurich **has no center** - it's not like Geneve.  You won't find one.

Answer (score 12):

The center of Zurich is not very big, and most places in Zurich are actually whole streets and areas that are interesting. Generally you can consider the whole area between the [Bahnhofstrasse](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Bahnhofstrasse,+Zurich,+Switzerland&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x47900a0a4578c013:0x96371feb65728644!3m8!1m3!1d3346!2d8.5386692!3d47.3719504!3m2!1i1920!2i951!4f13.1!4m2!3d47.373681!4d8.538523), [Bahhofbrücke](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Bahnhofbr%C3%BCcke,+8001+Z%C3%BCrich,+Switzerland&data=!4m12!2m11!1m10!1s0x47900a080fbbed5b:0xf1427c56edda90fe!3m8!1m3!1d3346!2d8.545985!3d47.3748493!3m2!1i1920!2i951!4f13.1), [Seilergraben](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=seilergraben,+Zurich,+Switzerland&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x479aa0a8605e5f5b:0x5d6f0bf087df50a3!3m8!1m3!1d25897!2d8.5414124!3d47.3665187!3m2!1i1920!2i920!4f13.1!4m2!3d47.3747637!4d8.5458925), [Rämistrasse](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=R%C3%A4mistrasse+8001,+Zurich,+Switzerland&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x479aa0a939dff26b:0xec86006239c5c892!3m8!1m3!1d3346!2d8.5426667!3d47.3768977!3m2!1i1920!2i951!4f13.1!4m2!3d47.3705512!4d8.5491561),  and the [Quaibrücke](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Quaibr%C3%BCcke+8001,+Zurich,+Switzerland&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x479aa0aad147f27d:0x12713d35b3749241!3m8!1m3!1d3346!2d8.5472746!3d47.3745338!3m2!1i1920!2i951!4f13.1!4m2!3d47.366933!4d8.5430905) as the inner center of the city (more or less the district [Kreis 1](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Kreis+1,+Zurich,+Switzerland&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x47900a0a466ab94d:0x22994931f0229c0f!3m8!1m3!1d6692!2d8.5434846!3d47.373634!3m2!1i1920!2i951!4f13.1!4m2!3d47.37!4d8.542). There are some more places of course. Here some places to walk along:

1. The old city called Niederdorf, from [Central](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Central+1,+8001+Z%C3%BCrich,+Switzerland&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x479aa0a7f798bb7d:0xfb83b5c6f1fcc41e!3m8!1m3!1d1673!2d8.54459!3d47.3766631!3m2!1i1920!2i951!4f13.1!4m2!3d47.3770095!4d8.5437145) to the [Grossmünster](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Grossm%C3%BCnster,+Grossm%C3%BCnsterplatz,+Zurich,+Switzerland&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x479aa0aa49df6165:0x491a251494535f10!3m8!1m3!1d6692!2d8.5392056!3d47.3715835!3m2!1i1920!2i951!4f13.1!4m2!3d47.370093!4d8.544054) and [Bellevue](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Bellevueplatz,+Zurich,+Switzerland&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x479aa0ab478bc1b3:0x6557bc6b7a3e3d02!3m8!1m3!1d3346!2d8.5441002!3d47.3699432!3m2!1i1920!2i951!4f13.1!4m2!3d47.367059!4d8.545114), connected through the [Niederdorfstrasse](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Niederdorfstrasse,+Zurich,+Switzerland&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x479aa0a83a3c8b5d:0x320636673c71375!3m8!1m3!1d3346!2d8.5451137!3d47.3670591!3m2!1i1920!2i951!4f13.1!4m2!3d47.3745983!4d8.5438408) and then the [Neustadtgasse](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Neustadtgasse,+Zurich,+Switzerland&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x479aa0abb9ef262f:0xfbe7c9dd55193977!3m8!1m3!1d3346!2d8.543872!3d47.3745641!3m2!1i1920!2i951!4f13.1!4m2!3d47.3698399!4d8.5452773). Alternatively (or on the way back) along the river on the [LimmatQuai](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Limmatquai,+8001+Z%C3%BCrich,+Switzerland&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x479aa0ab1e88dec7:0x9f46aa94d8d20818!3m8!1m3!1d1673!2d8.5433623!3d47.3705163!3m2!1i1920!2i951!4f13.1!4m2!3d47.3679917!4d8.5440818).
2. The Bahnhofstrasse, starting at the main station [Hauptbahnhof](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Hauptbahnhof,+Z%C3%BCrich,+Switzerland&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x47900a08f1939f4b:0xb2730efc3f8af0bb!3m8!1m3!1d3346!2d8.5439636!3d47.3679231!3m2!1i1920!2i951!4f13.1!4m2!3d47.378188!4d8.539204) going until the [Paradeplatz](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Paradeplatz,+Z%C3%BCrich,+Switzerland&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x47900a00f892871d:0xde64cfb1d69cccaa!3m8!1m3!1d13384!2d8.5388851!3d47.3696873!3m2!1i1920!2i951!4f13.1!4m2!3d47.369688!4d8.538885) and then further to the [Bürkliplatz](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=B%C3%BCrkliplatz,+Z%C3%BCrich,+Switzerland&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x479aa7554d8ceabb:0xa19fec85c2fc3012!3m8!1m3!1d13384!2d8.5388851!3d47.3696873!3m2!1i1920!2i951!4f13.1!4m2!3d47.3663744!4d8.5411285), turning towards Bellevue via the bridge Quaibrücke.
3. Alternatively the path from the Hauptbahnhof, along the Bahnhofsstrasse, but then turning left on the [Rennweg](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Rennweg,+Z%C3%BCrich,+Switzerland&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x47900a071f515e17:0x94f5d74aeab2cc6a!3m8!1m3!1d3346!2d8.5411261!3d47.3664227!3m2!1i1920!2i951!4f13.1!4m2!3d47.3730738!4d8.5395359) going straight up the mountain until the [Fraumünster](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Fraum%C3%BCnster,+Zurich,+Switzerland&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x47900a00864f7ab7:0xadee790c683facbe!3m8!1m3!1d3346!2d8.5395909!3d47.3730143!3m2!1i1920!2i951!4f13.1!4m2!3d47.369834!4d8.541355), also back along the [Stadhausquai](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Stadthausquai,+8001+Z%C3%BCrich,+Switzerland&data=!4m12!2m11!1m10!1s0x479aa0aa90a21293:0x6cb98348c84e9072!3m8!1m3!1d3346!2d8.5413551!3d47.3698339!3m2!1i1920!2i951!4f13.1)
4. As a park area, the Utoquai, starting at Bellevue again and going along the lake until the [Blatterwiese](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Blatterwiese,+8001+Z%C3%BCrich,+Switzerland&data=!4m15!1m14!4m8!1m3!1d1674!2d8.5512859!3d47.3539759!3m2!1i1920!2i951!4f13.1!10b1!26m3!1e12!1e13!1e3).
5. As a relatively new area with a lot of night entertainment, modern design shops and a generally relaxed area, inside the [Kreis 5](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Kreis+5,+Zurich,+Switzerland&data=!1m4!1m3!1d12944!2d8.5193753!3d47.3864399!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x47900a0f5a0fc927:0x7cd3ecf9f5cf57be!3m8!1m3!1d3347!2d8.5510218!3d47.3545619!3m2!1i1920!2i951!4f13.1!4m2!3d47.388!4d8.521) area with the [Geroldstrasse](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Geroldstrasse,+Zurich,+Switzerland&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x47900a3fb6b757af:0xd8a9f120eeb03042!3m8!1m3!1d12944!2d8.5193753!3d47.3864399!3m2!1i1920!2i920!4f13.1!4m2!3d47.3856941!4d8.5197295), [Viaduktstrasse](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Viaduktstrasse,+Zurich,+Switzerland&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x47900a1537645d0f:0xfbb225d1728864e0!3m8!1m3!1d809!2d8.5198538!3d47.3857403!3m2!1i1920!2i920!4f13.1!4m2!3d47.3871442!4d8.524322) and the Josefswiese park.

Comment: Exactly like Los Angeles, Zurich notably and famously *has no center*.  No emotional / spiritual / core center.  This is an obvious fact about the city.

Answer (score 8):

The central point of Zurich I'd consider to be the [main station](https://maps.google.ch/maps?q=47.377822,8.540472&num=1&t=h&z=16).

Other points that could be considered being the city centre:

- the [old town](https://maps.google.ch/maps?q=47.370295,8.544356&num=1&t=h&z=16) with historic buildings
- the [Bahnhofstrasse](https://maps.google.ch/maps?q=47.375744,8.53942&num=1&t=h&z=16) which is a famous shopping street
- and maybe [Bellevue](https://maps.google.ch/maps?q=47.367185,8.544699&num=1&t=h&z=16) at the lakeside which is where a lot of events take place

All those places are pretty central.

Comment: +1 I would say that the center stretches from the main station to the lake along Bahnhofstrasse and the river.

Comment: Agreed, but I would definitely include the old town, which is on the other side of the Limmat.

Answer (score 1):

For such geographical investigations, I'm mostly using wikimapia.org (could be described as a community of people drawing polygons on a satellite maps to describe what's depicted).

So, you can see here the polygon [Zentrum Historisch von Zurich](http://wikimapia.org/#lang=en&lat=47.372169&lon=8.542857&z=15&m=b) ([permalink](http://wikimapia.org/24064419/it/Zentrum-Historisch-von-Zurich)).

Disclaimer: I've never been to Zurich, so I can't tell how accurate is this perception of Zurich's city center.

Comment: That's really cool! It corresponds to the area described by the other answers.

Comment: Yes, can confirm. It's one of the nicest areas in Zurich to explore, lots of small hidden shops in narrow streets, really fun.

Comment: This must be one of the worst answers on the internet.